# How can I get the CSS Selectors for an element by value in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, css-selectors, cheerio

I am writing a web scraper with Node and considering using a module like Cheerio or JSDom to parse the HTML into a DOM for a set of URLs. However, I have a specific functionality that is necessary.

My objective is to build a scraper that can scrape multiple similar pages on a site for a few key pieces of information. However, I have some sample data that contains these pieces of information, and I want to use them to dynamically build a model for those pages and then scrape the rest of site using that model.

To clarify, if there are three pages on a site, each containing a different product:

Page 1:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Product 1</h1>
<p>Desc</p>
<small>$2.05</small>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Product 2</h1>
<p>Desc</p>
<small>$8.05</small>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 3:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Product 3</h1>
<p>Desc</p>
<small>$5.07</small>
</body>
</html>
```

Say I already have the data for the first product (I know the Product Name, Desc, and Price). I want to get the selectors of each of those elements using the first page, and then use those selectors to scrape data from the other pages.

Given the content of a tag in the DOM, how can I get the CSS Selector for that element? For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I provide Cheerio/JSDom with a string like "Hello world" and have it return the CSS Selector in the DOM where the element resides?

Is there an easy way to do this (including using another framework), or is the only way just to loop through the entire DOM object and check the values of each element individually?

Comment: There will be multiple different XPaths that return the same nodelist. Which one do you want? I assume `//*[text()='Hello world']` is not what you're after?

Comment: What do you want to find out? As you could have an XPath as simple as `//*[. = "Hello world"]`

Comment: All I want is to find the element/path where the element that contains "hello world" is, so I can use that path to extract other information later. Basically, I'm automatically building my scraping model using seed data.

Comment: And what if there's more that one node that matches?

Comment: Then just get the path of the first one. Is XPATH the best way to do this? Just looking for some overall guidance about the easiest way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest and most efficient to accomplish with the [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) model, but can be applied to DOM traversal instead.

```
var match, path = [];

parser.on('start', function(tag) { currentPath.push(tag); });
parser.on('end', function(tag) { currentPath.pop(); });

parser.on('text', function(text) {
  if (!match && text === 'Hello world') {
    match = path.join('/');
  }
});
```

If you need to build the DOM anyway, you can use XPath to find the node (which internally just loops the whole DOM), then loop up the parents.

```
var path = [];
var node = document.xpath('//*[.="Hello world"]')[0];

do { 
  path.push(node.tag);
} while (node = node.parent);

var match = path.reverse().join('/');
```

This second method is a lot more inefficient, especially if you have many different nodes to find. The SAX method can cover all of them in a single pass, but may struggle with malformed input depending on the parser implementation.

For CSS selectors, replace `'/'` with `' > '`.

Comment: In your first suggestion, what is the parser object? Could you provide a more comprehensive review of what your code does?

Comment: It's a SAX parser. Presumably some kind of `Stream` you can pipe the response through, or an `EventEmitter` that you can give a DOM to run over.

Comment: I just amended my question to ask about CSS selectors instead. Does your SAX solution still apply?

Comment: @ChandlerFreeman The fact that you can't tell suggests you don't really know what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple proof of concept with Cheerio, following the similar "walk up the tree" strategy as [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41854860/6243352):

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <small>Hello world</small>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
let x = [...$(":contains(Hello world)")]
  .find(e => $(e).contents().length === 1); // find a leaf node
const path = [];

for (; x.tagName !== "body"; x = x.parent) {
  path.push(x.tagName);
}

const selector = path.reverse().join(" > ");
console.log($(selector).text()); // => Hello world
```

That said, there are a *lot* of potential edge cases here. If an element has multiple children, you'll need to disambiguate them and select the n-th child, or loop over them. If there are ids or classes, those are likely more reliable than simple tag names--you could add checks for ids on the way back up the tree and stop if you hit one.

Instead of trying to write one general algorithm to rule them all, it's generally better to use whatever domain knowledge is available for the page structure. For example, if you know a particular unique class will be on each page, you might use that to disambiguate and improve accuracy of the above general approach applied to your use case.